# Requiring to render a 30-days notice?

Tags: resignation

Im currently working with a salary of 12000 and the scope of my job was Im only the one incharge in Rice sales (DR, Billing, Collection, Deposit) and aside from that my employer also have a personal errands for me to make and also under accounting dept. they also have errands that Im the one who make which is not scope of my job. Then I tried to find a new job, and got hired with a 30,000 monthly salary but then they only given me 1-week endorsement. then I filed a resignation but they refuse to accept because they want me to render a 30-days notice. Can they filed me an abandonment of duty if I pursue my resignation with 1 week notice only or any legal obigation?

Comment: The country (and currency) would be important when trying to answer this.

Comment: I am guessing India, for no good reason...?

Comment: @keshlam From the name I'm guessing Philippines/Indonesia, but it's still just a guess. Op needs to clarify

Comment: Yes..,...........................................

Answer (score 1):

**What does your employment contract with your current company say ?**

If the contract says that you must have a 30-day notice or the employer can decide how long the notice period is, then unfortunately, you have to follow the contract.

However, if your contract does not say how long the notice period is, then you are free to quit after 1 week as you wish. **At least, this is how it works in the US.**

---

**In the US, in the IT industry**, if a company doesn't have a written contract that defines how long the notice period is, then whenever possible, it is **customary** to have a notice period of 2 weeks. This is just a nice gesture of both sides to ensure a smooth transfer of knowledge before you leave. However, if you really need to leave within 1 week, then you can try to talk to your boss and they would try to work it out with you.

Comment: If the contract *or law in the OP's jurisdiction* does not say anything, anyway. For example, there are "default" notice periods written in UK law which will apply even if there is nothing in the contract.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, Can you tell us how long those default notice periods are in the UK ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 There are many jurisdictions where there are statutory requirements around giving (and receiving) notice. In addition, there may be industry specific collective bargaining agreement that could also change notice conditions. Note, 24% of US employees are not at-will.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Let's wait for the OP to clarify which jurisdiction they _are_ in; they're pretty clearly not in the UK.

Comment: @Job_September_2020, for reference in the UK, after one full month's service, both employer and employee are required to give one week's notice to end the contract. It's also not unusual for staff jobs to contractually require a month's notice on either side. And the employee (but not the employer) also benefits from longer statutory notice periods for longer service, the formula is broadly a week's notice required for every full year of service.